# Windows 2008 64 bit OS and 32 bit COM EXE's

Tags: windows, oop, com, windows-server-2008

getting a COM error trying to run 32 bit OOP COM exe's on a 64 bit OS.

Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

If I have a compiled 32bit EXE that reads registry for GUID's how do I resolve this?

David D

Comment: Is that 32-bit program a COM server or a consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer... The .NET solutions I had were set to "Any CPU".  Once I changed it to x86... this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably a registration problem.  The type library is used when you use the standard marshaller for the out-of-process server.  Which uses the info in the type library to figure out how to properly serialize the arguments of a function call.  On a 64-bit machine, the type library needs to be registered in the HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Classes/Typelib key.  It is referenced by the TypeLib key in the registry key for the interface, a subkey of HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Classes/Interface.

Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to observe where it is looking, contact the server's vendor or author for installer support.

Comment: yeah ..well We are the software vendor.  Just didn't think we would have to rewrite this process to run it on a 64bit OS.  No workarounds at all?  some 3rd party thing that intercepts and redirects?

Comment: Workaround for what?  Find the source of the problem first, then you'll know how to fix it.  Use Regedit.exe and ProcMon.

Comment: ok so how does a tlb get registered?  when I tried the regtlibv12.exe .... didn't do anything

Comment: That's the job of the installer for the COM component.  Or its DllRegisterServer entrypoint, depends.

Comment: ok... when I ran procomon... everything seemed to be looking at WOW6432Node .. but the registry entries for this GUID seem to be there and in the other one too.

Comment: Did you see the Typelib key being read?  Is the file actually present on the disk?

Comment: so when I run procmon it's not showing a problem.  The typelib is on the disk, it is registered.  IF I unregister it, it gives a different error of NO_INTERFACE.

Comment: I am taking the GUID and doing a Type.GetTypeFromCLSID() to then instantiate the instance of this type.  IS this still ok in 64bit?

Comment: No, the bitness matters a great deal.  It is not going to find the registry entries if the app runs as a 64-bit process.  GetTypeFromCLSID also requires the interop library, created by Tlbimp.exe.  I'm seriously lost at what you try to do and where the error occurs.

Comment: We have a .NET managed Service that is the runner of these 32bit COM OOP Exe's ... it instantiates them to run the code.    I am wondering if it has to do with the fact we have SecurityPermissionAttribute and SecurityPermissionFlag.Unmanagedcode etc around this method that creates the com object by guid?  I didn't write this code.. it's been in place for years... trying to figure out myself.  Don't want to have to rewrite all these EXE's into .NET.